Block Theme: Is there a way to know which global style is active for a page?
I'm building a block theme with multiple global style templates (multiple theme/styles/styleName.json files).
From what I can tell, WordPress does not appear to inject the name of the selected global style into the page HTML. I was hoping to find something like:
<body class="has-global-style-styleName">

But that does not appear to be the case. Is there a way to know this information? If not, is there a strategy that might work to gather that info?
For context, the reason I need to know this is because there's a custom style that uses a border image. I need to use a different border image for Global Style X versus Global Style Y.

note that the current global style is not a direct result of the JSON file but a layering of theme.json, the style, and what's in the database, along with any child/parent theme considerations, it isn't directly read and used as is from styleName.json, but rather that file is loaded and contributes to the overrall style settings, so it's very possible in the future that the answer to is it using style A or style B might be: "Yes" as unhelpful as that sounds
